# How is original plain text length reconstructed after decryption under RSA?

Tags: encryption, rsa, padding

So far I know the ciphered output length of RSA equals the modulus N.

If I have only a small block of data significantly smaller than N, is the rest of the input to RSA just zero padded?

How can deciphering be unique then?

For instance if I get back as a plaintext

`P="XXXXXXXXXXXX000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...."`,
how can I know, how many zeros had been in the original plain text: 
It could be

`"XXXXXXXXXXXX"` or also `"XXXXXXXXXXXX000000"` as well as `"XXXXXXXXXXXX0"`

All those plaintexts would give the same ciphered text after padding.

Comment: Usually, paddings either include the length of the message, or more commonly (like PKCS 1.5) a marker marking the point between message and padding. In your case, one would typically append one 1-bit before filling up with zeroes, which wouldn't be safe due to the mathematic structure of RSA. Instead, one should use paddings like OAEP. EDIT: Just saw @dade's answer :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most importantly, note that for almost all practical applications textbook RSA **should not be used** to encrypt something. It does not yield an encryption scheme which provides the guarantees one would expect in practice. In particular it does not even provide security against [chosen plaintext attacks (IND-CPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability).

Instead one would use some padding scheme such as [optimal asymmetric encryption padding (OAEP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding).

Despite the fact that the usage of RSA you describe should not be used in practice, you would typically not pad "XXXXXXXXXXXX" as "XXXXXXXXXXXX000000....". Instead, you would encode "XXXXXXXXXXXX" as a number between 1 and N and use this upon encryption (i.e., you only implicitly prefix it with zeroes).